# Is it possible to call a Firebase function for a secret, execute some code and then call another function with the encrypted data?

Tags: android, security, google-cloud-functions

I have been having some security problems with my app for months. Even using NDK to store a secret key, some users have been able to extract the secret and exploit my app.

I use Firebase functions within my app, and I was thinking of creating about something like this:

[image]

With this, I have a new secret for each validation. Now, my problem: is it possible to do this with Firebase functions? I have some functions that are called from the app, but they do their work and return some data. In this case, I will need to execute a function, return the data to the app, and execute another function, knowing the previously created secret.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create tasks that process the information on completion of another, this includes checking the status of a task

**A**
Chain event example

```java
Single.create(sub -> {

                doSomethingHere

                sub.onSuccess(true);
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    //.compose(bindToLifecycle())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object o) {

                          ExecuteTheNextThing();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                          errorHandling 

                        }
                    });
        }
```

for the above example - requires the following in your build gradle

```java
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:+'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:+'
```

**B**
If you want to go with manual tasks, you can use the Check Status

```java
 if (asynclass.getStatus() == android.os.AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
     asynclass.execute();
 } else if (RF.getStatus() == android.os.AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
     asynclass = new asyncclass();
     asynclass.execute();
 } else {
     Toast.maketoast(this, "Plz wait", 1).show();
 }
```

Additional reading Async tasks: https://medium.com/android-news/some-asynchronous-options-on-android-cb6b0c156c98